# Changing domain of the CGF of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, moment-generating-functions

Given a stochastic cadlag process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Define $A_{t}$ as the domain of the cumulant generating function by $f_t(s):=\log E(e^{sX_t})$, for which this expression is welldefined. I search for an example, where the domain $A_{t}$ changes in time. So for some $t_1\not= t_2$ that $A_{t_1}$ and $A_{t_{2}}$ don't coincide.

Comment: Choose $X_t=tX$ with $X$ standard exponential, then $A_t=(-\infty,1/t)$ for every $t>0$.

Comment: @Did you want to post it as a answer, so i can sign this post as solved?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may post an answer yourself, based either on the example in my comment or on another one.